# SQL selecting average score over range of dates

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables:

```
doctors (id, name) -> has_many:
    patients (id, doctor_id, name) -> has_many:
        health_conditions (id, patient_id, note, created_at)
```

Every day each patient gets added a health condition with a note from 1 to 10 where 10 is a good health (full recovery if you may).

What I want to extract is the following 3 statistics for the last 30 days (month):
 - how many patients got better
 - how many patients got worst
 - how many patients remained the same

These statistics are global so I don't care right now of statistics per doctor which I could extract given the right query.

The trick is that the query needs to extract the current health_condition note and compare with the average of past days (this month without today) so one needs to extract today's note and an average of the other days excluding this one.

I don't think the query needs to define who went up/down/same since I can loop and decide that. Just today vs. rest of the month will be sufficient I guess.

Here's what I have so far which obv. doesn't work because it only returns one result due to the limit applied:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.name,
    hc.latest,
    hcc.average
FROM
    pacients p
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            id,
            pacient_id,
            note as LATEST
        FROM
            health_conditions
        GROUP BY pacient_id, id
        ORDER BY created_at DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) hc ON(hc.pacient_id=p.id)
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            id,
            pacient_id,
            avg(note) AS average
        FROM
            health_conditions
        GROUP BY pacient_id, id
    ) hcc ON(hcc.pacient_id=p.id AND hcc.id!=hc.id)
WHERE
    date_part('epoch',date_trunc('day', hcc.created_at))
    BETWEEN
        (date_part('epoch',date_trunc('day', hc.created_at)) - (30 * 86400))
    AND
        date_part('epoch',date_trunc('day', hc.created_at))
```

The query has all the logic it needs to distinguish between what is latest and average but that limit kills everything. I need that limit to extract the latest result which is used to compare with past results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this assuming `created_at` is of type `date`

```
select p.name,
       hc.note as current_note,
       av.avg_note
from patients p
   join health_conditions hc on hc.patient_id = p.id
   join (
      select patient_id, 
             avg(note) as avg_note
      from health_conditions hc2
      where created_at between current_date - 30 and current_date - 1
      group by patient_id
    ) avg on t.patient_id = hc.patient_id
where hc.created_at = current_date;
```

This is PostgreSQL syntax. I'm not sure if MySQL supports date arithmetics the same way.

Edit:

This should get you the most recent note for each patient, plus the average for the last 30 days:

```
select p.name,
       hc.created_at as last_note_date
       hc.note as current_note,
       t.avg_note
from patients p
   join health_conditions hc 
     on hc.patient_id = p.id
    and hc.created_at = (select max(created_at) 
                         from health_conditions hc2 
                         where hc2.patient_id = hc.patient_id)
   join (
      select patient_id, 
             avg(note) as avg_note
      from health_conditions hc3
      where created_at between current_date - 30 and current_date - 1
      group by patient_id
    ) t on t.patient_id = hc.patient_id
```

Comment: In MySQL you can do date arithmetic with `date_sub(yourdate, INTERVAL 20 day)`. For the current date, you can use `CURRENT_DATE()`.

Comment: The question was to obtain # of patients who have worsened, remained the same and improved...

Comment: @eggyal: well the question said: "*I don't think the query needs to define who went up/down/same since I can loop and decide that*" and "*Just today vs. rest of the month will be sufficient I guess*"

Comment: Thank you for your input @a_horse_with_no_name and @eggyal . Your query looks ok but there's a problem which I also faced. If the admin runs the report before the pacient statuses were added so today has no entries he will see nothing given the fact that your condition `where hc.created_at = current_date` filters it.

Comment: @GigiContra: well the query can't show, what isn't there. Or do you want to see a null value for the current note in case "today" does not have one?

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I need to show them the status of pacients for the last month (last 30 days if you like) which means that in this query I will need to extract the last results as today even if last results means yesterday (if today wasn't added yet).
Imagine this graph: http://jsfiddle.net/Qt2qy/

That's what I need to show even if today wasn't added the hospital manager needs to see the results.

Comment: @GigiContra: so if there is no data for today you want to see yesterday's data? What if some patients have data for today and some don't

Comment: I don't know. That's why I need help. To find a solution with you guys. Manager wants to see stats. He doesn't care about which entry was added when. This would make a great visual addition to a hospital admin if I can make it right. They will be able to break down to doctors and treatments to see who's got better results and try to fix things. I guess we don't have to worry about today or yesterday but we need to extract the last entry(ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1) and consider that as today/yesterday/whetever. Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: @GigiContra: The "use the latest" doesn't work if only part of the patients have data for "the latest".

Comment: @GigiContra: see my second query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you. I really appreciate your efforts and patience with my dumb questions.

Comment: @GigiContra: note that this is not 100% correct as the average will be calculated over the last 30 days regardless on when the most recent note was (if that was 10 days ago the avg will only cover 20 days).

Comment: Yeah I got that part. I'll go 30 days behind the last result.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name second query is somewhat close but you will still have an issue with grouping the results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/b6739/4 did you figure that out?

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea: You incorrectly grouped by the created_at column in the second derived table that's why you get those additional rows. See here: sqlfiddle.com/#!1/b6739/28

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(delta < 0) AS worsened,
       SUM(delta = 0) AS no_change,
       SUM(delta > 0) AS improved
FROM  (
  SELECT   patient_id,
           SUM(IF(DATE(created_at) = CURDATE(),note,NULL))
         - AVG(IF(DATE(created_at) < CURDATE(),note,NULL)) AS delta
  FROM     health_conditions
  WHERE    DATE(created_at) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND CURDATE()
  GROUP BY patient_id
) t
```

Comment: I'll try this approach also. Thanks @eggyal