# SQL SELECT last entry without limiting

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, limit

I have a table with 3 fields:

```
id
note
created_at
```

Is there a way in the SQL language especially Postgres that I can select the value of the last `note` without having to `LIMIT 1`?

Normal query:

```
select note from table order by created_at desc limit 1
```

I'm interested in something avoiding the limit since I'll need it as a subquery.

Comment: "I'm interested in something avoiding the limit since I'll need it as a subquery." That's a silly reason to avoid using a useful feature. What's the *real* reason? What is your actual problem? Post your code and the error you get. What are your requirements and concerns? Explain why LIMIT doesn't satisfy your requirements.

Comment: It's related to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112990/sql-selecting-average-score-over-range-of-dates

Comment: [Ain't no such thing as "Postgre"](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines) - I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your id column is an autoincrementing primary key field, it's pretty easy. This assumes the latest note has the highest id.  (That might not be true; only you know that!)

```
select *
  from note
 where id = (select max(id) from note)
```

It's here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7478a/1/0 for MySQL and here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/6597d/1/0 for postgreSQL. Same SQL.

If your id column isn't set up so the latest note has the highest id, but still is a primary key (that is, still has unique values in each row), it's a little harder.  We have to disambiguate identical dates; we'll do this by choosing, arbitrarily, the highest id.

```
select *
  from note
  where id = (
              select max(id)
                from note where created_at = 
                   (select max(created_at) 
                      from note
                   )
              )
```

Here's an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f802/4/0 for MySQL.
Here it is for postgreSQL (the SQL is the same, yay!) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/bca8c/1/0

Another possibility: maybe you want *both* notes shown together in one row if they were both created at the same exact time.  Again, only you know that.

```
select group_concat(note separator '; ') 
  from note 
 where created_at = (select max(created_at) from note)
```

In postgreSQL 9+, it's

```
 select string_agg(note, '; ') 
   from note 
  where created_at = (select max(created_at) from note)
```

If you do have the possibility for duplicate created_at times and duplicate id values, and you don't want the group_concat effect, you are unfortunately stuck with LIMIT.

Comment: As to your last statement: Well, there are window functions for PostgreSQL and the substitute with variables for MySQL.

Answer (score 7):

#### Simple version with [EXISTS semi-join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS):

```
SELECT note FROM tbl t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM tbl t1 WHERE t1.created_at > t.created_at);
```

"Find a note where no other note was created later."

This shares the weakness of @Hogan's version that it can return **multiple rows** if `created_at` is not `UNIQUE` - like @Ollie already pointed out. Unlike @Hogan's query (`max()` is only defined for simple types) this one can be improved easily:

#### Compare row types

```
SELECT note FROM tbl t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 FROM tbl t1
    WHERE  (t1.created_at, t1.id) > (t.created_at, t.id));
```

Assuming you want the greatest `id` in case of a tie with `created_at`, and `id` is the primary key, therefore unique. This works in PostgreSQL and MySQL.

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26117/1)

#### Window function

The same can be achieved with a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in **PostgreSQL**:

```
SELECT note
FROM  (
    SELECT note, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY created_at DESC, id DESC) AS rn
    FROM   tbl t 
    ) x
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

**MySQL** lacks support for window functions. You can substitute with a variable like this:

```
SELECT note
FROM  (
    SELECT note, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rn
    FROM   tbl t 
         ,(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    ORDER  BY created_at DESC, id DESC
    ) x
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

`(SELECT @rownum := 0) r` initializes the variable with 0 without an explicit `SET` command.

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26117/5)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% on Postgres (actually never used it) but you can get the same effect with something like this - if the `created_at` is unique ... (or with any column which is unique):

```
SELECT note FROM table WHERE created_at = (
    SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM table
)
```

Comment: That's doesn't do the same. It's not guaranteed to return only one row (unless there is a unique contraint on `created_at`).

Comment: @MarkByers - I would have sworn my answer says "if the dates are unique".  Did you not read the 2nd line?

Answer (score -1):

I may not know how to answer on this platform but what I have suggested is working

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY field ORDER BY max(field) DESC;
```

You can get the last value of the field without limiting, usually in JOINED query we get the last update time with no limiting of output like this way, such as last message time without limiting it.