# What type of JOIN to use

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, join, zoho

What type of JOIN would I use to get `table1` and `table2` to be matched only once. For example, I have `table1` (40 rows) and `table2` (10000 rows). But I get `table1` repeated over and over when I use a join on      `table1.LocationArea =  table2.Location`

```
What I get:                         What I wish I could get:
t1.LocationArea,t2.Location         t1.LocationArea,t2.Location
---------------------------         ---------------------------
az,az                               az,az
az,az                               null,az
ca,ca                               ca,ca
il,il                               il,il
tx,tx                               tx,tx
tx,tx                               null,tx
az,az                               null,az
                                    null,il
                                    null,ca
```

I wish to end up with 10000 records in the query.

I have tried `inner join`, `left`, and I am using ZOHO reports which does not support outer join's.

```
SELECT "table1"."LocationArea", "Location" 
FROM "table2"
left join "table1" on  "Location" = "table1"."LocationArea"
```

Comment: What exactly are you using?  Your question mentions ZOHO, but you've also tagged the question with mysql, sql-server and postgresql.  Which one is it?

Comment: It would also be really helpful if you would show your table structure, some sample data and what you have already tried.  Otherwise the best we can do is just guess how to help you.

Comment: Ok sorry was trying to find a solution using any sql program and maybe us it in ZOHO reports because they state that they use most sql programs commands in zoho...(but they don't have all the commands)

Comment: have you tried using distinct?

Comment: Yes. but it will chopped table2 down. Maybe im using it wrong.

Comment: SELECT distinct"table1"."LocationArea", "Location" FROM "table2" left join   "table1" on   "Location" = "table1"."LocationArea" and it give me back 19 records. im trying to keep the 10,000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you have duplicate values for both of the joining columns. Instead of the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) an `[INNER] JOIN` would produce for this, you want each row to be used only *once*. You can achieve this by adding a row number (`rn`) per duplicate and join on `rn` additionally.

Each table can have more or fewer dupes for the same value than the other unless you have additional restrictions in place (like a FK constraint) - but there is nothing in your question. To keep *all* rows one would use a [**`FULL [OUTER] JOIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM). But you want to keep 10000 records in the result, which is the cardinality of `table2`. So it must be a [**`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) on `table1` (with 40 rows) - and exclude possible excessive rows from `table1`.

```
SELECT t1."LocationArea", t2."Location"
FROM  (
   SELECT "Location"
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY "Location") AS rn
   FROM   table2
   ) t2
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT "LocationArea"
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY "LocationArea") AS rn
   FROM   table1
   ) t1 ON t1."LocationArea" = t2."Location"
       AND t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

Works for Postgres or SQL Server. MySQL doesn't support window functions, you would need a substitute:

- [SQL SELECT last entry without limiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117349/sql-select-last-entry-without-limiting/12118416#12118416)

To be clear: `LEFT JOIN` is just shorthand for `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, so you are already using an outer join. Your statement is a *misunderstanding*:

> I am using ZOHO reports which does not support outer join's.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON `table_1_primary_key` = `table_2_primary_key`
```

Or
    SELECT colname FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON `table_1.colname` = `table_2.colname`

Depending on the structure of your database

Comment: tried this but get the table1 with 40 records repeated over and over

Comment: use fully qualified names...like table1.colname, table2.colname