# Prevent duplicate values in LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, join

I faced a situation where I got duplicate values from `LEFT JOIN`. I think this might be a desired behavior but unlike from what I want.

I have three tables: **`person`**, **`department`** and **`contact`**.

**person :**

```
id bigint,
person_name character varying(255)
```

**department :**

```
person_id bigint,
department_name character varying(255)
```

**contact :**

```
person_id bigint,
phone_number character varying(255)
```

**Sql Query :**

```
SELECT p.id, p.person_name, d.department_name, c.phone_number 
FROM person p
  LEFT JOIN department d 
    ON p.id = d.person_id
  LEFT JOIN contact c 
    ON p.id = c.person_id;
```

**Result :**

```
id|person_name|department_name|phone_number
--+-----------+---------------+------------
1 |"John"     |"Finance"      |"023451"
1 |"John"     |"Finance"      |"99478"
1 |"John"     |"Finance"      |"67890"
1 |"John"     |"Marketing"    |"023451"
1 |"John"     |"Marketing"    |"99478"
1 |"John"     |"Marketing"    |"67890"
2 |"Barbara"  |"Finance"      |""
3 |"Michelle" |""             |"005634"
```

I know it's what joins do, keeping multiplied with selected rows. But It gives a sense like phone numbers `023451`,`99478`,`67890` are for both departments while they are only related to person john with unnecessary repeated values which will escalate the problem with larger data set. 

So, here is what I want:

```
id|person_name|department_name|phone_number
--+-----------+---------------+------------
1 |"John"     |"Finance"      |"023451"
1 |"John"     |"Marketing"    |"99478"
1 |"John"     |""             |"67890"
2 |"Barbara"  |"Finance"      |""
3 |"Michelle" |""             |"005634"
```

This is a sample of my situation and I am using a large set of tables and queries. So, kind of need a generic solution.

Comment: Preventing duplicates for any inner or left join is handled by correctly joining along the multiplicities (and having them right at the start!). The result currently shown is 'correct' - or else information would be lost.

Comment: the results you desire are absolutely arbitrary, because there is no relation between contact and department in the schema

Comment: @Beginner- postgres db. Does it matter ? Its basic sql right ?

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ I know its kind of arbitrary, but the result creates many redundancy. any help to achieve my desired result. Do I need to change schema for this ?

Comment: @user2864740 what could be possible right join structure to prevent this ?

Comment: how do you know for `Finance` the phone number is `023451` I dont see any relation between dept and contact.

Comment: You expected o/p is random and has not any relations. You can get results like `1 |"jhon"     |"Finance"      |"023451,99478,67890"` using `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I know expected output is unreasonable.Here I want something. Its like person->contact (one-to-many), person->department(one-to-many). If a user wants to see person detail along with his contacts and departments information, what would be the perfect way ? FYI, considering large data set, concatenation seems unreasonable.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I like to call this problem **"cross join by proxy"**. Since there is no information (`WHERE` or `JOIN` condition) how the tables `department` and `contact` are supposed to match up, they are cross-joined via the proxy table `person` - giving you the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Very similar to this one:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

More explanation there.

Solution for your query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.person_name, d.department_name, c.phone_number
FROM   person p
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT person_id, min(department_name) AS department_name
   FROM   department
   GROUP  BY person_id
   ) d ON d.person_id = p.id
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT person_id, min(phone_number) AS phone_number
   FROM   contact
   GROUP  BY person_id
   ) c ON c.person_id = p.id;
```

You did not define *which* department or phone number to pick, so I arbitrarily chose the *minimum*. You can have it any other way ...

Comment: thanks for the information. I got the problem here. But  according to your query, what if a user wants first department, phone number in first row, then second one in second row like so on. It sounds ridiculous but any ideas ?

Comment: Like may be use sequence or something on both department and contact table to retrieve corresponding records without duplicating.

Comment: could it be possible with any sub-query ?

Comment: @GautamKumarSamal: How would you define "first". Unlike in a spreadsheet, there is no natural order in a table of an RDBMS. If you can define first, you could run `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY <criteria>) AS rn` and then `LEFT JOIN` in the row number in the subquery. Start a *new question* with all details if it's still unclear. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034827/what-type-of-join-to-use/28035613#28035613

Comment: you seem to chose `MIN` rather `FIRST`, no?

Comment: @jangorecki: Yes, fixed my wording accordingly. If you  need the first, according to some other sort order, use `DISTINCT ON ( person_id)` in the subqueries. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860

Answer (score 6):

I think you just need to get lists of departments and phones for particular person. So just use [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-aggregate.html) (or `string_agg` or `json_agg`):

```sql
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.person_name,
    array_agg(d.department_name) as "department_names",
    array_agg(c.phone_number) as "phone_numbers"
FROM person AS p
LEFT JOIN department AS d ON p.id = d.person_id
LEFT JOIN contact AS c on p.id = c.person_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.person_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the tables are obviously simplified for discussion, it appears they are structurally flawed. Tables should be structured to show relationships between entities, rather than be merely lists of entities and/or attributes. And I would consider a phone number to be an attribute (of a person or department entity) in this case.

The first step would be to create tables with relationships, each having a primary key and possibly a foreign key. In this example, it would be helpful to have the person table use person_id for the primary key, and the department table to use department_id for its primary key. Next look for one-to-many or many-to-many relationships, and set your foreign keys accordingly:

- If one person can only be in one department at a time, then you have a one(department)-to-many(persons). No foreign key in the department table, but department_id will be a foreign key in the persons table.
- If one person can be in more than one department, they you have a many-to-many, and you'll need an additional junction table with person_id and department_id as foreign keys.

To summarize, there should only be two tables in your scenario: one table for the person and the other table for the department. Even allowing for personal phone numbers (a column in the persons table) and department numbers in the department table, this would be a better approach.

The only caveat is when one department has many numbers (or more than one department shares a single phone number), but this would be beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: Thanks for replay. Like you suggested, I had primary-foreign relationships among them. Its like person->contact (one-to-many), person->department(one-to-many). If a user wants to see person along with his contacts and departments information, what would be the perfect way ?

Comment: You already have person_id as a foreign key in the departments table, which is a great start. I would next turn the contacts table into a column in the persons table. Contact info isn't suitable for a stand-alone table.

Comment: I suspect your phone numbers may be a combination of department numbers and person numbers. If it is a mixture of both types, you'll have to  somehow distinguish the difference, either with a temporary "flag" column, or query using IN(...) with a comma-delimited list of department numbers.

Comment: contact table is quite large in my case. It not only stores phone number, but also every details like blood group, marital status , address and so..So, its a stand-alone table

Answer (score 1):

Use this type of query: *SQL Server*
(You can change `id` of `ORDER BY id` to each column that you want it)

```
SELECT 
    p.id, 
    p.person_name, 
    d.department_name, 
    c.phone_number
FROM
    person p
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY id) AS seq
     FROM department) d 
    ON d.person_id = p.id And d.seq = 1
    LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY id) AS seq
     FROM contact) c 
    ON c.person_id = p.id And c.seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.id, p.person_name, d.department_name, c.phone_number 
FROM person p
  LEFT JOIN department d 
    ON p.id = d.person_id
  LEFT JOIN contact c 
    ON p.id = c.person_id 
group by p.id, p.person_name, d.department_name, c.phone_number
```

Comment: Won't this give the same result? Since in the original example there are no two rows with all of the same [id, person, dept, phone] values, grouping by those fields wouldn't change anything.