# Concatenate values with LEFT join

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

While searching, I came across a very similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410622/prevent-duplicate-values-in-left-join#)
but I have an additional question to what has been posted there already.

```
id|person_name|department_name|phone_number
--+-----------+---------------+------------
1 |"John"     |"Finance"      |"023451"
1 |"John"     |"Finance"      |"99478"
1 |"John"     |"Finance"      |"67890"
1 |"John"     |"Marketing"    |"023451"
1 |"John"     |"Marketing"    |"99478"
1 |"John"     |"Marketing"    |"67890"
2 |"Barbara"  |"Finance"      |""
3 |"Michelle" |""             |"005634"
```

Lets say I want the final result as:

```
id|person_name|department_name|phone_number
--+-----------+---------------+------------
1 |"John"     |"Finance"      |"023451", "99478", "67890"
1 |"John"     |"Marketing"    |"023451", "99478", "67890"
2 |"Barbara"  |"Finance"      |""
3 |"Michelle" |""             |"005634"
```

basically similar results from `phone_number` concatenated; then can you advise what should I be doing ? I tried GROUP_CONCAT with DISTINCT but it didn't help.

Comment: Why did you tag every RDBMS? Regardless, there are so many answers for this specific question on SO for each that you should not have any problem finding the answer.

Comment: Lots of Db servers tagged, which do you want a solution for?

Comment: removed other tags based off the comment of GROUP_CONCAT

Answer (score 0):

So this will pivot and comma delimit your Numbers which I believe is the desired effect? This is a SQL Server solution

```
declare @t table (OrderedID int, EmpName varchar(50), EmpDep varchar(50), Num varchar(50))

insert into @t
values
(1,'John','Dep1','123')
,(1,'John','Dep1','456')
,(1,'John','Dep2','789')
,(2,'Doug','Dep1','987')
,(2,'Doug','Dep1','654')
,(2,'Steve','Dep2','321')


Select
*
From @t

SELECT distinct e.EmpName,
  e.EmpDep,
  LEFT(r.Num , LEN(r.Num)-1) num
FROM @t e
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT r.Num + ', '
    FROM @t r
    where e.EmpName = r.EmpName
      and e.EmpDep = r.EmpDep
    FOR XML PATH('')
) r (Num)
```

Ouput:

```
EmpName EmpDep  num
Doug    Dep1    987, 654
John    Dep1    123, 456
John    Dep2    789
Steve   Dep2    321
```