# MySQL - Get top 5 opponents

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the top 5 opponents I played against.

The tables are as follow

```
USERS :
 user_id  name               email
       1 : Gait Bakker     : user1@test.nl
       2 : Freek ter Bekke : user2@test.nl
       3 : Jan Zomer       : user3@test.nl
       4 : Mick Dundee     : user4@test.nl
       5 : Sjoerd Trekhaar : user@test.nl

GAMES :
    game_id type training **created_by started_by **opponent_id won_by date
          1    1        1          2              2           4      2 2015-08-10
          2    1        1          5              2           2      5 2015-08-10
          3    1        1          4              4           2      4 2015-08-10
          3    1        1          2              3           3      3 2015-08-10
```

The problem is the fields with ** and that it needs to count the top 5 opponents.

**I can be the game creator (created_by)** and **I can be the opponent_id** (someone else started the game).

Still if I am the opponent I played against another player.

**Edit** 
Please use user-id = 2 for example.

As additional : Training needs to be 1 and won_by IS NOT NULL (needs to be filled in)

Result SQL
Most played against opponent

```
user_id = 4,  count = 2
user_id = 3,  count = 1
user_id = 5,  count = 1
```

So that means I played the most against user-id 4 and then user_id = 3 and user_id = 5

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry : Use user_id = 2, but every logged in user has another user-id.

Comment: @jarlh Training = 1 AND won_by IS NOT NULL

Comment: @Strawberry, you're Strawberry!

Comment: @Strawberry : Pleas use user_id = 2 (for the info : I mean that when I log in I have user_id 2 and I want to know my top 5 opponents, but when Jan Zomer logs in with user_id 3 he wants to know his top 5 opponents)

Comment: @Strawberry : I would glad add the SQL, however because of the problem that I (user-id 2) can have started the game or be the opponent I don't even know where to start with the query (I would think a sub query) :

We tried this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984130/add-up-conditional-counts-on-multiple-columns-of-the-same-table

Comment: @Strawberry : I edited the post, this is want you mean ?

Comment: No, I was looking for CREATE and INSERT statements (just enough to be properly representative of the problem), and a corresponding desired result.

Answer (score -1):

As per my Understanding, Top opponent will be considered based on the `Won_By`

```
 SELECT TOP 5 NAME, COUNT(*) as COUNTS FROM USERS
  INNER JOIN
  GAMES
  ON GAMES.WON_BY = USERS.user_id
  WHERE user_id <> Logon_ID
  GROUP BY NAME
  ORDER BY COUNTS
```

Derive the `Logon_ID` according to your code

Comment: Thank you for your reply

I mean the top most played matched against an opponent, won or lost (see my edit in my post)