# Uniting data into one row

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have the following data:

```
materials
==========================
id       | quantity |type
---------+----------+-----
1        |111       |1
2        |240       |2
3        |412       |2
4        |523       |1
```

For the sake of the simplicity of the example, let's say I need to select materials into pairs by types, so the desirable result would look like that:

```
id       | quantity |type |id       | quantity |type
---------+----------+-----+---------+----------+-----
1        |111       |1    |2        |240       |2
4        |412       |1    |3        |412       |2
```

Data will match perfectly, so there would be no empty entries in pairs.
So far I can think only of `union`, like that:

```
select * from materials where type = 1
union all
select * from materials where type = 2
```

But obviously, that's not what I'm looking for. Is that even possible?
P.S. Please, do not simplify the answer to `...where type in (1,2)`, because actual condition is not mergeable like that.

Comment: Don't you need another table to keep track of the pairs?

Comment: What do you mean by "into pairs by types"?  That seems to suggest that you would want to join the two rows with `type` =1, and join the two rows with `type`=2, but your output shows that you have joined items of different type.  Why did those particular rows get joined?

Comment: @LucasKrupinski no, I guess not. That data would go straight to the clientside, and dapper will take care of that.

Comment: @rd_nielsen I meant that I need to return pairs in which one entry is of type=1 and the other is of type=2

Comment: Why is `id`=1 grouped with `id`=2 instead of with `id`=3?

Comment: @rd_nielsen Well, that's not relevant, strictly speaking. In actual code conditions will find enties that exactly need to be paired. So far, I need help with finding a way to combine the 2 rows in one.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28035613/939860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "conditions will find entities that exactly need to be paired" results in a table called `pairs` with columns `id1` and `id2` then

```
select
    p.id1,
    m1.quantity,
    m1.type,
    p.id2,
    m2.quantity,
    m2.type
from
    pairs p
    inner join materials as m1 on m1.id=p.id1
    inner join materials as m2 on m2.id=p.id2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can JOIN separate queries for type 1 and 2. Eeach query with `row_number()` function

```
create table materials(
  id integer primary key,
  quantity integer,
  type integer
);

insert into materials values
  (1, 111, 1),
  (2, 240, 2),
  (3, 412, 2),
  (4, 523, 1),
  (5, 555, 2),
  (6, 666, 1);

select * 
  from (
    select *, row_number() over (order by id) as rownum
      from materials
      where type=1
    ) t1 inner join (
    select *, row_number() over (order by id) as rownum
      from materials
      where type=2
    ) t2 on t1.rownum = t2.rownum
```

You can try it here: http://rextester.com/XMGD76001

*Refs*:

- row_number(): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html
- inner join: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html

Comment: I think that it should be `full join`

Comment: May be `full join`. But if you are sure that the two subqueries matchs `inner join` is most performant. If you not you must handle the `nulls` when you fetch the data

Comment: doesn't seem to work as expected. btw, I don't need that your solution would match my "desirable result" exactly, so the trick with row_number is unnececcary. I just need the way to pair results of two subqueries.

Comment: Sorry. I make a typo. I write type=1 twice. The seconds was type=2. Try it now in your postgresql (dbfidle does not accepts columns with the same name)

Comment: If you look at http://rextester.com/XMGD76001 and delete rows with id 5 and 6 you get exact your example. I add 5 and 6 to be sure that works with more data.

Comment: I belive that `row_number` is needed to say "the first with the first, the second with the second..."